# How can I access the trained parameters of a Neural ODE in Julia?

Tags: julia, ode, differential-equations, flux.jl, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to fit one Neural ODE to a time series usind Julia's DiffEqFlux. Here my code:

```
u0 = Float32[2.;0]
train_size = 15
tspan_train = (0.0f0,0.75f0)

function trueODEfunc(du,u,p,t)
    true_A = [-0.1 2.0; -2.0 -0.1]
    du .= ((u.^3)'true_A)'
end

t_train = range(tspan_train[1],tspan_train[2],length = train_size)
prob = ODEProblem(trueODEfunc, u0, tspan_train)
ode_data_train = Array(solve(prob, Tsit5(),saveat=t_train))

dudt = Chain(
            Dense(2,50,tanh),
            Dense(50,2))
ps = Flux.params(dudt)
n_ode = NeuralODE(dudt, tspan_train, Tsit5(), saveat = t_train, reltol=1e-7, abstol=1e-9)

**n_ode.p**

function predict_n_ode(p)
    n_ode(u0,p)
end
function loss_n_ode(p)
    pred = predict_n_ode(p)
    loss = sum(abs2, ode_data_train .- pred)
    loss,pred
end

final_p = []
losses = []
cb = function(p,l,pred)
    display(l)
    display(p)
    push!(final_p, p)
    push!(losses,l)
    pl = scatter(t_train, ode_data_train[1,:],label="data")
    scatter!(pl,t_train,pred[1,:],label="prediction")
    display(plot(pl))
end

DiffEqFlux.sciml_train!(loss_n_ode, n_ode.p, ADAM(0.05), cb = cb, maxiters = 100)

**n_ode.p**
```

The problem is that calling `n_ode.p` (or `Flux.params(dudt)`) before and after the train function gives me back the save values. I would have expected to receive the latest updated values from the training. That's why I've created an array to gather all parameter values during the training and then access it to get the updated parameters.

Am I doing something wrong in the code? Does the train function automatically update the parameters? If not how to enforce it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is an object that holds the best parameters. Here's a complete example:

```
using DiffEqFlux, OrdinaryDiffEq, Flux, Optim, Plots

u0 = Float32[2.; 0.]
datasize = 30
tspan = (0.0f0,1.5f0)

function trueODEfunc(du,u,p,t)
    true_A = [-0.1 2.0; -2.0 -0.1]
    du .= ((u.^3)'true_A)'
end
t = range(tspan[1],tspan[2],length=datasize)
prob = ODEProblem(trueODEfunc,u0,tspan)
ode_data = Array(solve(prob,Tsit5(),saveat=t))

dudt2 = FastChain((x,p) -> x.^3,
            FastDense(2,50,tanh),
            FastDense(50,2))
n_ode = NeuralODE(dudt2,tspan,Tsit5(),saveat=t)

function predict_n_ode(p)
  n_ode(u0,p)
end

function loss_n_ode(p)
    pred = predict_n_ode(p)
    loss = sum(abs2,ode_data .- pred)
    loss,pred
end

loss_n_ode(n_ode.p) # n_ode.p stores the initial parameters of the neural ODE

cb = function (p,l,pred;doplot=false) #callback function to observe training
  display(l)
  # plot current prediction against data
  if doplot
    pl = scatter(t,ode_data[1,:],label="data")
    scatter!(pl,t,pred[1,:],label="prediction")
    display(plot(pl))
  end
  return false
end

# Display the ODE with the initial parameter values.
cb(n_ode.p,loss_n_ode(n_ode.p)...)

res1 = DiffEqFlux.sciml_train(loss_n_ode, n_ode.p, ADAM(0.05), cb = cb, maxiters = 300)
cb(res1.minimizer,loss_n_ode(res1.minimizer)...;doplot=true)
res2 = DiffEqFlux.sciml_train(loss_n_ode, res1.minimizer, LBFGS(), cb = cb)
cb(res2.minimizer,loss_n_ode(res2.minimizer)...;doplot=true)

# result is res2 as an Optim.jl object
# res2.minimizer are the best parameters
# res2.minimum is the best loss
```

At the end, the `sciml_train` function returns a result object that holds information about the optimization, including the final parameters as `.minimizer`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! One more small question- in the definition of the network, I don't understand why we need to transform the input with (x,p) -> x.^3 first. I thought the network should not have any knowledge of the original ODE?

Comment: The purpose of this example is to show that things do better when you utilize whatever knowledge you have of the original ODE. Our recent preprint [Universal Differential Equations for Scientific Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04385) takes this idea much further as does [this blog post](https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/how-to-train-interpretable-neural-networks-that-accurately-extrapolate-from-small-data/). Personally, I see this as the main reason to use an ODE form.

Comment: Btw I noticed that the .minimizer gives indeed the last parameters, but not the "best" ones, i.e. not the ones that achieved the minimum loss.

Comment: It does with the Optim optimizers but not the Flux ones. We can manually work around that though. Please open an issue

Comment: Issue to track this: https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqFlux.jl/issues/170